# Dynamically calculating the number of rows in a Flutter PaginatedDataTable based on a given height

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with Flutter's `PaginatedDataTable` in a web app, and I'm trying to make it automatically calculate and display the maximum number of rows that can fit within the available height. I have a predefined height for each row and the header, and I'm using the `LayoutBuilder` to get the available height and then compute the `rowsPerPage`.

```
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    final double rowHeight = 50.0;
    final double headerHeight = 70.0;
    final double availableHeight = constraints.maxHeight - headerHeight;
    final int rowsPerPage = (availableHeight / rowHeight).floor();

    return PaginatedDataTable(
      rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage,
      // Add other properties as needed
    );
  },
);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work perfectly. The table always displays too many rows, causing overflow, or too few rows, leading to wasted space.

I would be open to doing it the other way around and defining rows and calculating height after that. But I tried that and same result.